# Force delete a page or component

Tags: content-manager, 2011-sp1

I believe we are not able to delete some pages/component after publishing all because we are turning publications on/off. Although I have unpublish from all current publications, it still says it is published to somewhere when trying to delete.
If there a way where I can delete those pages/components (without going to DB using SQL)?

Comment: Nick provides the publication target approach. At least for SDL Tridion 2009 and 2011, Chris Summers and Frank van Puffelen describe how to [do the same with code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11327484/395495).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Alvin for pointing out the solution using code. I think I like this solution better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327484/how-to-set-ispublishedto-status-on-a-tridion-component

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is a way. Tridion 2013 has a feature to decommission publishing targets.  However, since your question is regarding Tridion 2011 SP1, you can resort to a technique where you fake the publication target to which your page is published to. Tanner Brine explains this technique here: http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/tricking-tridion-into-unpublishing-content-from-dead-targets

Comment: The solution seems fine but it is also quite time consuming, especially if we have changed many publications (add/remove/change). I am hoping there is some thing simpler but  I am less optimistic there is a simple solution now.